# mongodb (mongoose) throws E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a state model which is a lookup with just a name that i have set to unique because i don't want two states with the same name. now I have vacation model with a state property that i have set to the state schema. error E11000 duplicate key error collection is thrown after the first vacation is inserted when I insert a second vacation with the same state.I know mongodb throws the exception because I already have a vacation with the state.name as the first one.

```
const stateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 30,
    unique: true
  }
});

const State = mongoose.model("State", stateSchema);

------------------------------------------------------

const vacationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

-- some properties

  state: {
    type: stateSchema,
    required: true
  }

-- some properties

});

const Vacation = mongoose.model("Vacation", vacationSchema);
```

so how can i force unique state names in the states collection, but allow multiple vacations to have the same state in the vacations state? do I have to explicitly change state: {type: stateSchema} to {type: new Schema(...etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two options :

1. If there is only one field **name** in State collection, also if it doesn't change(kind of nothing like rename/alter), Plus every vacation document contains only one state name then you would include **state name** value in **state field** directly in your **Vacation** document, this helps in if you don't want to hit other collection every time you query **Vacation** plus no need to maintain two collections. There is no point of directly storing names in **Vacation** collection if you're maintaining **State** collection, as there won't be any validation whether a given name exists in State collection or not, unless you do a DB call to check it before inserts to Vacation, because storing data into collections is independent - So you might need to remove `unique : true` from `stateSchema`, your code should work, as the above code is about storing data into **Vacation** or simply in Vacation schema make State as string & use State schema for storing data into State Collection.
2. Or if you really need to maintain another collection as what you've now, then you need to have a mapping between documents in **State** collection to documents in **Vacation**. This is helpful if most documents in **Vacation** will have multiple **State** names in array field. Where State names are unique in **State** collection. Optimal way of having relation is thru `_id` of State documents. If need to do that then make changes in **Vacation** Schema as,

   ```
   state: {
     type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'State' }],// you can make this single value instead of array.
     required: true
   }
   ```

   After this you need to use .populate() on reads - Ref : [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

   If you want to store state name as value in **Vacation** collection, then make state field as string, then you can use .populate() on reads - Ref : [mongoose populate virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) or similar to mongoDB's native `$lookup` - Ref : [mongoDB $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

**Note :**

1. Uniqueness on State name helps when you've transactions related to State and also you need separate collection when you need to make frequent changes only on State related data + on reads as well you need only data related to State or Vacation - you make those independent as State is unique you can refer that in vacation.
2. Not only in mongoose schema, you also create `unique` index on a field, that way it will be on DB level which helps either way when running queries directly on DB or thru code, whereas mongoose schema triggers thru code, Also when you create an unique index on existing collection & runs into issue means there is already duplicate data for that field.

Comment: I need to maintain the State collecting because in my frontend there is a drop-down that I need to display all States so you can choose from them, the drop-down selects an Id so I query that state and store it's name along with the id in the Vacation document, the reason I'm not using objectId, ref and populate is because i don't want two calls to db every time I query a Vacation

Comment: @alkhatim : you don't need to calls to query Vacation and get respective state name using populate or $lookup !! more over if you need to maintain state name(instead of _id ref) in two collections then any update to state name would cause updating in multiple collections, ok anyway if you need things working then you can make state as string in vacation schema as suggested in answer i.e; not using state schema inside vacation schema !!

Comment: @alkhatim : I mean two* calls in the above comment, Did it work ?

Comment: yea I changed the State property in the Vacation schema to string and now all's good

Comment: sorry I forgot!